# How to concat or merge three tables with different number of columns in pandas?

Tags: json, pandas, merge, concatenation

My trouble began with a JSON file, where I have certain "device" information, with certain parameters for different devices.

I am able to capture each device json like as a single row DataFrame for each device. And they'd have 40-60 columns including common columns.

A sample data is given below :

[image]

Reproducible code :

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': {0: 1122},
 'c1': {0: 'uid'},
 'c2': {0: 'iopw'},
 'c3': {0: 'uywy'},
 'c4': {0: '7uyw'},
 'c5': {0: 'iwoq'},
 'c6': {0: 'owoe'}}
)

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id': {0: 9910},
 'c1': {0: 'mnjjj'},
 'c3': {0: 'mhji'},
 'c6': {0: 'mb '},
 'c8': {0: 'bly'},
 'c14': {0: 'bnhg'},
 'c15': {0: 'kkkl'},
 'c20': {0: 'llug'},
 'c25': {0: '87jo'}})


df3 = pd.DataFrame({'id': {0: 2020},
 'c4': {0: 'kvkh'},
 'c5': {0: 'kjhjkh'},
 'c10': {0: 'cvcvc'},
 'c15': {0: 'ququ'}})
```

I have tried merging, but the problem in the below code that I have tried is that it is creating duplicate columns.

```
dfs = [df1, df2, df3]
from functools import reduce
df_final = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on='id',how="outer"), dfs)
```

How can I avoid that duplicates or, is there any other cleaner way of concatenating or merging the tables so that I am devoid of any repeat columns?

---

The expected output is shown below. It shall have 3 rows, and the correct number of columns

```
{'id': {0: 1122, 1: 9910, 2: 2020},
 'c1': {0: 'uid', 1: 'mnjj', 2: nan},
 'c2': {0: 'iopw', 1: nan, 2: nan},
 'c3': {0: 'uywy', 1: nan, 2: nan},
 'c4': {0: '7uyw', 1: nan, 2: 'kvkh'},
 'c5': {0: 'iwoq', 1: nan, 2: 'kjhjkh'},
 'c6': {0: 'owoe', 1: 'mb', 2: nan},
 'c7': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan},
 'c8': {0: nan, 1: 'bly', 2: nan},
 'c9': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan},
 'c10': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: 'cvcvc'},
 'c11': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan},
 'c12': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan},
 'c13': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan},
 'c14': {0: nan, 1: 'bnhg', 2: nan},
 'c15': {0: nan, 1: 'kkkl', 2: 'ququ'},
 'c16': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan},
 'c17': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan},
 'c18': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan},
 'c19': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan},
 'c20': {0: nan, 1: 'llug', 2: nan},
 'c21': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan},
 'c22': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan},
 'c23': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan},
 'c24': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan},
 'c25': {0: nan, 1: '87jo', 2: nan}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with created index by `id` with [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
dfs = [df1, df2, df3]

df = pd.concat([x.set_index('id') for x in dfs], sort=True)
print (df)
_t')
         c1    c10   c14   c15    c2   c20   c25    c3    c4      c5    c6  \
id                                                                           
1122    uid    NaN   NaN   NaN  iopw   NaN   NaN  uywy  7uyw    iwoq  owoe   
9910  mnjjj    NaN  bnhg  kkkl   NaN  llug  87jo  mhji   NaN     NaN   mb    
2020    NaN  cvcvc   NaN  ququ   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  kvkh  kjhjkh   NaN   

       c8  
id         
1122  NaN  
9910  bly  
2020  NaN
```

Then for add all possible combinations of `c` columns use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
maxim = df.columns.str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False).astype(int).max()
cols = [f'c{x}' for x in range(1, maxim+1)]
df = df.reindex(columns = cols).reset_index()
print (df)
     id     c1    c2    c3    c4      c5    c6  c7   c8  c9  ... c16  c17  \
0  1122    uid  iopw  uywy  7uyw    iwoq  owoe NaN  NaN NaN  ... NaN  NaN   
1  9910  mnjjj   NaN  mhji   NaN     NaN   mb  NaN  bly NaN  ... NaN  NaN   
2  2020    NaN   NaN   NaN  kvkh  kjhjkh   NaN NaN  NaN NaN  ... NaN  NaN   

   c18  c19   c20 c21  c22  c23  c24   c25  
0  NaN  NaN   NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  
1  NaN  NaN  llug NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  87jo  
2  NaN  NaN   NaN NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  

[3 rows x 26 columns]
```